# Bootstrap 3.1.1 links inside ".dropdown-menu li > a" and jquery event "onClick" on it's "a" nodes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

On `$(document).ready()` I initialize my script and do replacing some nodes with this:

```
<div class="btn-group live-block" live_id="city-live" initialized="yes">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="city-live">
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="live-element" val="4400">Kiev</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="live-element" val="4401">New York</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="live-element" val="4402">Moscow</a></li>
   </ul>
   <input type="hidden" name="" value="">   
</div>
```

and
I can't set event "onClick" to this `a` inside `li`

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.live-element', function(e){
        console.log(123);
        e.preventDefault();
})
```

Anywhere inside HTML DOM this works, but not inside bootstrap class `dropdown-menu`
Help me please to do this `li > a` clickable!
P.S. Do not propose me to change name of bootstrap class `dropdown-menu` because I want that my code become friendly with bootstrap.

Comment: You don't have any `li` elements?

Comment: you have no `li` tags under `ul` ?

Comment: Yes, I have! (just did a mistake on copy-paste code here)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do anything on it's own. Can you post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Upgrade to Bootstrap v3.2.0 too.

Comment: upgrading is impossible, because template what i need to use based on 3.1.1 and upgrading will override default styles

Comment: i have found solution where use:
$(document).on('click', 'a.live-element', function(e){
        console.log(123);
        e.preventDefault();
})

it reference on bootstrap jquery plugins codes, that do something onClick on `li > a` elements. But it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.live-element', function(e){
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log(123);
        e.preventDefault();

})
```

This helps me